# creating array to be used with http_build_query

Tags: php

How do I rewrite this?

```
command=v&amount=<amount>&currency=<currency>&client_ip_addr=<ip>&description=<desc>&language=<language>&msg_type=SMS(&<property_name>=<property_value>)
```

into this?

```
$post_fields = array(
                     'command'        => 'v',
                     'amount'         => $amount,
                     'currency'       => $currency,
                     'client_ip_addr' => $client_ip_addr,
                     'description'    => $description,
                     'language'       => $language,
                     'msg_type'       => "SMS(&${property_name}={$property_value}"
                    );
```

I'm curious about last part of the parameters. `SMS(` is it an array or something? did I write correctly inside array?

Comment: The `SMS` thing looks like a format recognized by the service you're sending the parameters to. It's just a character string that includes a `prop=value` inside it.

Comment: It looks to me like it should all be correct. Have you looked at the result of `http_build_query($post_fields)` to see if it looks good?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> ...&msg_type=SMS(&<property_name>=<property_value>)
> ```

If this is a query string from a URL, then the parameter value `SMS(&...)` should have been encoded as `SMS(%26...)` to distinguish the ampersand as a character value from the ampersand used to separate different parameters. The parentheses should probably be similarly encoded as `SMS%28%26...%29`.

Other than that, the thing inside the `SMS(...)` parameter value is probably meant to be parsed by the receiver of the query, and has no special meaning to the URL itself.

Your array re-formulation appears to be correct, except that you are missing a closing paren in the `msg_type` value:

```
<?php

  $amount         = '$3.99';
  $currency       = 'USD';
  $client_ip_addr = '2001:db8::42';
  $description    = 'Flumbar';
  $language       = 'en';
  $property_name  = 'glimb';
  $property_value = 'snord';

  $post_fields = array(
    'command'        => 'v',
    'amount'         => $amount,
    'currency'       => $currency,
    'client_ip_addr' => $client_ip_addr,
    'description'    => $description,
    'language'       => $language,
    'msg_type'       => "SMS(&${property_name}={$property_value})"
  );

  $s = http_build_query ($post_fields);
  echo "$s\n";

//  command=v&amount=%243.99&currency=USD&client_ip_addr=2001%3Adb8%3A%3A42&
//  description=Flumbar&language=en&msg_type=SMS%28%26glimb%3Dsnord%29
```